# Awk print $0 print all lines of my files to the last position of column ;how I can print at first?

Tags: awk

I use this command

```
  awk -F";" '{ print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' FILE3.csv
```

This print  well but this print in this order

VVVVVVVV;column10;**column1;column2;column3:column4;column5.....column10**

I need to print in reverse
**column1;column2;column3:column4;column5.....column10**;VVVVVVVV;column10

but not work how I can do this ?

Comment: Is the original file from Windows?  This would be the only thing I can think of as to why the order might change.  If so you either need to run dos2unix over it of change the RS to be the windows line ending.

Comment: yes is from windows

Comment: ok will do this ; very thank you

Comment: yes now works very thankyou

Comment: @VictorHernandez: You may try cat -v Input_file to check if control M characters are there or not, if they are there you could remove them by tr -d '\r' < Input_file and so on. Let us know how it goes then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Either you do**

```
$ awk -F";" '{ sub("\r",""); print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' file
```

**OR**

```
$ awk -F";" '{ print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' RS="\r\n" file
```

**OR**

```
$ dos2unix file
$ awk -F";" '{ print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' file
```

**Here is Example**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat file
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10

# See at the end there is ^M char
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat -A file
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10^M$
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10^M$

# Using awk without sub() - This is what you got
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -F";" '{ print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' file
VVVVVVVVcolumn10column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10
VVVVVVVVcolumn10column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10

# Using awk with sub() - This is what you wanted to get
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -F";" '{ sub("\r",""); print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' file
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10VVVVVVVVcolumn10
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10VVVVVVVVcolumn10

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -F";" '{ print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' RS="\r\n" file
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10VVVVVVVVcolumn10
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10VVVVVVVVcolumn10

# dos2unix
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ dos2unix file
dos2unix: converting file file to Unix format ...

# Now you can see ^M is not there
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat -A file
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10$
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10$

# Now your awk 
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -F";" '{ print $0 "VVVVVVVV" $10 }' file
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10VVVVVVVVcolumn10
column1;column2;column3;column4;column5;column6;column7;column8;column9;column10VVVVVVVVcolumn10
```